# How to remove pre-installed ubuntu and and install another OS?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-7

I bought a new PC with ubuntu11.10 pre-installed but now I want to use Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Wipe the HD first using Diskpart from Windows 7 DVD: [SSD / HDD : Optimize for Windows Reinstallation](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/91339-ssd-hdd-optimize-windows-reinstallation.html)

Follow these tips to get a purrfect clean reinstall - use the ones which apply: [re-install windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/125874-re-install-windows-7-a.html#post1086729)

SOURCE : http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/150731-install-windows-7-over-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Windows 7 installation will give you the option to format the hard drive.